# Email already taken (try / except)

Tags: django

I want to guide my user at the submit, that an email is already taken. On my subscribing form, i have this code.

```
def clean_email(self):
    try:
        emailCheck = User.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError('Email already exists')
```

I need to use the try / except because i have a problem when the user inserts correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use [`exists`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists).

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not.

Using `get` will return the user object which is unnecessary and less performant for this kind of validation.

```
if User.objects.filter(username=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
     raise ValidationError('Email already exists')
```

---

You may also be interested to know that the [`username`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.username) field in django only allows 30 characters which doesn't really play nicely for emails. There is a migration that should be available for Django 1.10 that puts this limit up to 150 characters.

Comment: Yes, `.exists()` method is better to use here for checking existence.

Answer (score 3):

`.filter()` method does not raise a [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) exception. You should instead **use `.get()` method** for raising those exceptions.

From [Django QuerySet docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get)

> `get()` raises a `DoesNotExist` exception if an object wasn’t found for
>   the given parameters. This exception is an attribute of the model
>   class.

```
def clean_email(self):
    try:
        emailCheck = User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise ValidationError('Email already exists')
```

**Note:** 
If you just want to check if a user with a given `username` exists, **you should use [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists) method**(as [@Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse) also suggested).

> Returns `True` if the QuerySet contains any results, and `False`
>   if not.

Comment: I will test your answer too, thank you for your course about DoesNotExist and .filter() :)